# Adding image to class Button Column

Tags: java, jtable, jbutton

I am using the wonderful class Button Column in my table (http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/07/12/table-button-column/)
I am trying to set an icon for the different states of the button in the table column using the methods setRolloverIcon and setPressedIcon. I tried inserting these in the constructor in the class and in the getTableCellRendererComponent method but that didn't work. I know how to have only an image in the button, or only text, but I need both. is there anyway to do that? Thanks

Comment: The ButtonColumn is a custom renderer written the author of the blog you mentioned. Look at the source code of that class, you can override getTableCellEditorComponent method and achieve what you are looking for.

Comment: I ended up solving the problem by editing the getTableCellRendererComponent, but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to change the icon by modifying the getTableCellRendererComponent as such:

```
if (isSelected)
    {
        renderButton.setForeground(myFColor1);
        renderButton.setBackground(myBColor1));
        renderButton.setIcon(nonactiveUpdate);
    }
    else
    {
        renderButton.setForeground(myFColor2);
        renderButton.setBackground(myBColor2);
        renderButton.setIcon(tableUpdate);
    }

    if (hasFocus)
    {
        renderButton.setForeground(myFColor3);
        renderButton.setBorder(BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(1, 1, 1, 1, new Color(252, 181, 73)));
        renderButton.setIcon(activeUpdate);
    }
    else
    {
        renderButton.setBorder( originalBorder );
    }
```